# Curl JSON encoded in UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, cygwin, json

**Important note**: I'm using **Cygwin**

---

I retrieve JSON from a file that I alter before sending it to a server using `curl`. By now everything is ok except one thing, when the server receive the JSON, every special characters (with accents, etc) aren't well encoded. I suppose this was due to the fact that my JSON wasn't encoded in UTF-8 before being sent but I don't manage to convert it.

Here is the code:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' $file
fileContent=`cat $file`

result=$(jq -c -j ".docs[$docIndex] + { \"_rev\": \"$rev\" }"<<<"$fileContent")            result="{\"docs\":[$result]}"

result=$result | sed 's/\r//g'
result=$result | iconv -t "UTF-8"
s=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d "$result" $2/$3/_bulk_docs --silent)
```

My bash script and my JSON files are both encoded in UTF-8.
My LANG variable seems to be UTF-8. I checked with this: `[[ $LANG =~ UTF-8$ ]] && echo "Uses UTF-8 encoding.."`

Any idea?

---

**Update**

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 = directory containing JSON files
# $2 = server url (+ port)
# $3 = database name

#Loop on every file of the given directory
for file in "$1"/*; do

    #Try to insert every document of a specific JSON file and retrieve their status (200 = OK; 409 = conflict)
    allStatus=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" --data-binary "@$file" $2/$3/_bulk_docs --silent | jq '.[] |.status' | tr -d '\r')
    docIndex=0

    #Loop on every status (one status = one document)
    while IFS=' ' read -ra statusArray; do
      for status in "${statusArray[@]}"; do

        #Remove unwanted windows characters of the file
        sed -i 's/\r//g' $file
        fileContent=`cat $file`

        #Retrieve the id of the current document
        id=`jq -r -j ".docs[$docIndex]._id"<<<"$fileContent" | tr -d '\r'`

        if [ "$status" = "409" ]
        then 
            #Retrieve the revision of the current document and add it to the document 
            rev=$(curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' $2/$3/$id?revs=true --silent | jq -r -j '._rev' | tr -d '\r')
            result=$(jq -c -j ".docs[$docIndex] + { \"_rev\": \"$rev\" }"<<<"$fileContent")

            #Wrap the document inside {"docs":[]}
            result="{\"docs\":[$result]}"

            #Remove unwanted windows characters before sending the document (again)
            result=$result | sed 's/\r//g'
            result=$result | iconv -t "UTF-8"
            s=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d "$result" $2/$3/_bulk_docs --silent)

            #Echo result
            echo $s
        else
          #Status should be 200.
          echo 'status: '$status ' - ' $id
        fi

        docIndex=$((docIndex+1))

      done
    done <<< "$allStatus"
done
```

This script aims to upsert documents inside a NoSQL database. If first try to insert and if if fails it retrieves a property (the revision) of the document, append to it and then retry once.

I know this script could be improved but this is my first bash script and it won't be used in production (only for testing, etc.).

Comment: Some questions: 1) what is the "jq" command?, 2) What Windows are you running on?  3) What happens if you don't use 'iconv'?  4) You use "$2" and "$3" in your curl command.  What are they (where do they come from?)  If they are parameters to your script what happened to "$1"?  5) where are you getting the json file from?   6) where is "$file" set?  I might have more, but it seems you are missing much detail from your question.  You'll need to supply more information to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Is my answer incorrect?

Comment: Utf-8 is now the default encoding in Unixes. If you have it set up as such, then there is no need to convert.

Comment: What is `result=$result | ….` should it be `result="$( echo "$result" | …"` — I added some safety quotes as well.

Comment: @Astara for #1: a pretty popular tool, installed by default on most modern linux distros https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: @cat I'm not sure if comments persist on deleted answers, but thanks for pointing out that my answer was incorrect!

Comment: @Parallaxbeta No problem :) (comments persist, but are only viewable to those who can view the deleted post itself - users with >=10k rep)

Comment: @Astara #1 a tool to work with JSON (see @cat comment). #2 Window 10 Pro. #3 I tried to use `iconv` to resolve the issue but without success, so it seems this line is useless. #4 You can see in my update the full script, $1 = # $1 = directory containing JSON files, $2 = server url (+ port), $3 = database name. #5 the JSON file comes from a directory stored on my Win10 computer. #6 see update with full script, it represent in file in the directory declared by $1 variable.

Comment: @richard I'm using Cygwin on a Windows environment, so the default UTF-8 you are talking about doesn't concern my use, is it? I replace `result = $result | ...`by `result="$( echo "$result" | ...)" as you suggested but it seems it does not change the comportment of these lines (or at least the result is the same).

Comment: fix bugs that you now know about, re-run, and amend question with new code (as run), and its inputs and outputs.

Comment: @MHogge -- don't use x=$(cmd w/multi line output) -- will cause problems.  if you are using cygwin-bash, use an array (i.e. "readarray -t out< <(cmd)" ) and to print it use 'printf "%s\n"  "${out[@]}" ' ...

Comment: @MHogge FYI -- jq seems to be "alpha" quality -- doesn't build (even after d/l'ing, rebuilding & installing new automake and bison) ...so am not likely to be able to reproduce your setup/tools;    BTW, though, your tools look to be UTF-8, so trying to convert them a 2nd time via iconv could introduce problems.  Also, you might want to use 'dos2unix' instead of using sed to get rid of CR's.  will only convert line endings.

Comment: Had a thought --  you say you are posting it to a website.  Problem is the default in websites *used* to be ISO-8859-1 !.  So if you have it encoded in UTF-8, maybe try re-encoding it from UTF-8 back into ISO-8859-1.  But, *warning*, ISO-8859-1 only has the first ~255 characters of UTF-8.  It doesn't support the rest!  So if you special meta chars are > U+0255, they might not be encodable by the website you are trying to upload them to.  Sorry didn't respond earlier, but stackexchange doesn't notify of new posts by email... so unless you vist all sites, you don't see updates. (lame)

Comment: Don't worry about the time, it's already very kind to help me about this. To be clearer, this is not really against a website that I do my http post but against a Couchbase Syncgateway api (if you know about it). I tried what you suggest with ISO-8859-1 but it didn't work either: here is what I have by encoding in UTF-8: http://hpics.li/d9899a4 and here is what I have by encoding to UTF-8 first and then re-encoding to ISO-8859-1: http://hpics.li/81421ae So you might see a little difference but well, it still not what I expect. Many thanks for the comments so far!

Comment: I manage to achieve what I wanted by switching from a bash script to a node.js one but still, I would like to know why this is isn't working with bash

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in Bash on Cygwin, as long as you at least have Python 2.7 installed:

```
utf8_result="$(echo "$result" | python -c "import sys;[sys.stdout.write((i).decode('utf-8')) for i in sys.stdin]")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

According to `man curl`, `-d` or `--data` does a POST using the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and is equivalent to `--data-ascii`. I don't think the attempts to override the header will change this. As the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) says, the charset for urlencoding depends on form elements, which are missing completely here.

If I understand your script correctly, `$result` is UTF-8, and not urlencoded. So you probably should use `--data-urlencode` (see `man curl` for details), and hope that it does encode UTF-8 correctly, or you should use `--form` instead, which is more flexible, and where you can include a charset field.

So the main problem seems to be in how the standard prescribes the encoding, which is sufficiently difficult to understand (at least for me). Maybe you can get a better answer on stackoverflow.